# How to share an Array of strings in multiprocessing in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am experimenting with Python's (v. 3.8) multiprocessing library, for developing a bigger program, and trying to share an `multiprocessing.Array` of strings between multiple processes such that this `Array` can be updated and read by each process with the same data. I tried `c_char_p` and it says to use `byte` strings. However, for this code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Array
from ctypes import c_char_p

def show(a):
    print("This ran")
    print("a: ", a[:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = Array(c_char_p, 1)
    array[0] = b'Hello World'
    print(array[:])
    p = Process(target=show, args=(array,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

the output varies from this:

```
[b'Hello World']
This ran
a:  [b'c']
```

to this:

```
[b'Hello World']
This ran
```

but I expect:

```
['Hello World']
This ran
['Hello World']
```

I guess an obvious solution would be to share a common file between each process but I expect to use multiple arrays and that can get a bit tedious. I was wondering what be the best current solution to this in Python 3.8.

For this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array
from ctypes import c_char_p

def show(a):
    print("This ran")

    # Decode the encoded values
    arr = [s.decode("utf-8") for s in a]
    print(arr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = Array(c_char_p, 1)
    message = b"Hello, world"
    array[0] = message

    p = Process(target=show, args=(array,))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    # Decode the encoded values
    arr = [s.decode("utf-8") for s in array]
    print(arr)
```

it never ends (i.e. never gets to the print statement after the process starts), the output is:

```
This ran
```

I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is *supposed* to work in general.

Basically, `c_char_p` is a pointer, a number that references a memory location in a process.
And you cannot expect pointers to be portable between processes.

Since Python `Process`-es *inherit* from their parent processes it *might* work for strings that were created before the child process was started.

But you cannot expect to create a new string in the child process, add a pointer to the Array and expect it to be valid in the parent process. (Nor the other way around.)

Using a `Pipe` or a `Queue` is probably a better way to exchange string data.

**Edit 1:**

Use a `Pipe` to send mutations of a list of strings, e.g. as a tuple `(3, "new value")`. This would mean that the item 3 in the list now becomes `"new value"`. Using a duplex `Pipe` means that both ends of the pipe can read and apply every message that comes in.

**Edit 2**:

Another option would be to use a [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers). This will allow you to share `list`s and `dict`s.

Comment: Okay, thanks. When I use a Queue, every time I use the get method to get the list in the Queue, the other processes now see an empty Queue when all I’m trying to do is get what’s in the Queue, update the list, then put it back in the Queue. How am I supposed to solve that problem?

Comment: You would at least need a pipe between the parent process and each child. The parent would have to send each message to all the children. The children only have to send it to the parent.

Comment: I never really worked with Pipes, do you mind showing an example of how to do that with at least two processes with an array of strings?

Comment: @user12055579 I don't have a good example on hand. I tend to use `multiprocessing.Pool` more than individual processes.

Comment: Okay. The thing about ```Pool``` is that you can't have shared memory between processes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210126/discussion-between-roland-smith-and-user12055579).

Answer (score 1):

The values are stored in `array` as the **encoded strings(byte values)**, so when you want the string values you have to **decode** them.

**Try this:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array
from ctypes import c_char_p

def show(a):
    print("This ran")

    # Decode the encoded values
    arr = [s.decode("utf-8") for s in a]
    print(arr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = Array(c_char_p, 1)
    array[0] = b"Hello, world"

    # Decode the encoded values
    arr = [s.decode("utf-8") for s in array]
    print(arr)

    p = Process(target=show, args=(array,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

**Output:**

```
['Hello, world']
This ran
['Hello, world']
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My output is not exactly like yours, I get: ```['Hello, world']
This ran
``` (with a blank line at the end)